# Focus in Math Field Widget not working when touch in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently utilizing the MathField widget in Flutter for text input. However, unlike the conventional TextField, I have observed that tapping on the MathField does not allow for cursor movement, restricting it solely to arrow keyboard navigation. Could you kindly provide guidance on resolving this issue to enable cursor movement through both tap and arrow keyboard input in the MathField widget?

I tried to make movement courser when tapping down but I couldn't find node position from global position.